# setOrientation is not working for LinearLayout programatically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am add dynamic data to the LinearLayout. default I declared as vertical orientation in xml. But I need to load horizontal data by programmatic way, Here set Orientation is not working.

```
LinearLayout llQuestionLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_question_layout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llQuestionLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    llQuestionLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

 private void populateLikert() {
    if(llQuestionLayout.getChildCount() > 0) {
        llQuestionLayout.removeAllViews();
    }


    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    for(int i =0; i < 5; i++) {
        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.likert_radio_button, null, false);
        radioButton.setText("" + (i + 1));
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton);
    }
    llQuestionLayout.addView(radioGroup);

}


<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_question_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Please suggest correct answer.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the `RadioGroup` that's still vertical? They're vertical by default. Or are you adding more than one `RadioGroup` to that `LinearLayout`, and those aren't right?

Comment: Oh Yes, the RadioGroup is still vertical. Thanks! Mike.